# Compile time Error libxml2.dylib

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5

I have found following error while compiling my project in xcode 5.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
1-In target Build Settings, Linking -> Other Linker Flags, add -lxml2
2-In target Build Settings, Search Paths -> Header Search Paths, add $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2
3-In target Build Phases, Link Binary With Libraries, add libxml2.dylib
```